# search in actionbar not appearing just in drop down

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar, searchview

So I am trying to add a search in the actionbar, following every example I can find, but no matter what I do, the search does not appear in the bar (only in the drop down, even though there is plenty of room for it), and the icon I have assigned never appears.

I have tried various minimal SDK version ranging from 8-11... and various styles as well, though this was the only style that explicitly mentions actionbar in the theme browse. (I assume due to the minSDK values)

I haven no idea what the heck is going on, everything I have read says it should be appearing, but it just doesn't, the search wills how up in the drop down (overflow) but only as text, no graphic.  I want it to appear as a graphic on the bar itself.:

Relevant Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
   .
    .
    .
 </application>
```

Menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.test2.MainActivity" >


<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
  android:title="search"
  android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
  android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

Code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);


    return true;
}
```

Comment: What version of Android are you testing it on?

Comment: I am using a device with 4.2.2 as my test device